# how to prevent other users to edit my profile in cakephp3

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp-3.0

I have simple program using cakephp3, when I try to directly put this into browser:

http://localhost/sample/users/edit/82

it directly goes to login page. Then after the login, my code still can edit the profile even that profile is not the current user login.

Below is my edit code

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
    $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
        'contain' => []
    ]);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);


                if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                    $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
                    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
                } else {
                    $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                }

    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
}


edit.ctp

<div class="actions columns large-2 medium-3">
<h3><?= __('Actions') ?></h3>
 <ul class="side-nav">
    <li><?= $this->Form->postLink(
            __('Delete'),
            ['action' => 'delete', $user->id],
            ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', 
  $user->id)]
        )
    ?></li>
    <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Users'), ['action' => 'index']) ?>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
    <div class="users form large-10 medium-9 columns">
     <?= $this->Form->create($user) ?>
   <fieldset>
      <legend><?= __('Edit User') ?></legend>
      <?php
          echo $this->Form->input('username');
          echo $this->Form->input('password');
      ?>
    </fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
  <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the existing user is trying to update his/her profile. You can do something like this.

All this on top of your edit method

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
  $logged_user_id=$this->Auth->user('id');

  if($logged_user_id==$id){
  $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
        'contain' => []
    ]);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);


                if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                    $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
                    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
                } else {
                    $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                }

    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
   } else {
                    $this->Flash->error(__('You are not allowed to do this.'));
     }
}
```

Comment: @bikash.biz                         but i cant edit my own profile after adding that code? anything to add?  even i am editing my id it will always "You are not allowed to do this."

Comment: @JeromeManatad YOu have to read your session for the current uses id. This variable ($logged_user_id) is storing the current logged user id. I am not sure about your table structure so this is what I guessed.

Comment: @JeromeManatad still If you can't do, please post your session array. You have write bellow code at the top of the edit action/method, it will print an array, post that array. pr($this->request->session()->read());die;

Comment: @bikash.bilz Given that the storage for authentication is configurable, you'd better use `$this->Auth->user()` instead of reading the session directly. Also please try to format your code a little more reabidly, this is especially important when it comes to control structures - thank you!

Comment: Notice (8): Undefined variable: user [APP/Template\Users\edit.ctp, line 6]
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP/Template\Users\edit.ctp, line 6]
Notice (8): Undefined variable: user [APP/Template\Users\edit.ctp, line 7]
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP/Template\Users\edit.ctp, line 7]

I add the edit code in the view above

Comment: I have updated the code again in the, please use the code and post the array so we can help you.

Comment: Array
(
    [username] => sample
    [id] => 82
    [email] => sample@gmail.com
    [profile_pic] => 0
    [destination] => 
    [created] => 2017-08-10
)

Comment: updated the answer, now it will help you @JeromeManatad

Comment: thank you so much for guiding me. Im new in cakephp im just practicing now. Thank you very much for your help, I hope you can help me through in the future. @bikash.bilz

Answer (score 0):

In my case and like ndm say, i don't use session, that's what i do (hope it helps):

```
public function edit($id = null)
{

    if(!is_null($this->Auth->user())): // if the user is logged
      if(is_null($id)) { $id = $this->Auth->user('id'); }
      if($this->Auth->user()['group_id']<>1): // in my case group 1 is for the administrator group, i let them edit profile
        $id = $this->Auth->user('id'); // in this case, if the user is not an administrator, id will always be his "user id"
      endif;      
    endif;

    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'edit', $id]);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }

    $this->set(compact('user'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
}
```

Comment: in your case? their will be group_id fields in users table?

Comment: yes, "groups" table is for roles, so group_id tell me for which role the user belong